# How can i update object using simple rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How can i update below `@rating` object from `form` ? I am getting

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `rating_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000007b4dd98>:0x007f3c88f1a4e8>):`
```

Custom method in Ratings controller:

```
def rate_user
    @rating = Rating.where(to: params[:friend], from: params[:user], user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
    render partial: 'edit_rating'
  end
```

partial  '_edit_rating.html.erb'

```
<div class="well">
    <%= form_for @rating do |f| %>
        <%= f.number_field :smoke_rate %>
        <%= f.number_field :drink_rate %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

Routes :

```
  resources :friendships
  resources :users do
    get 'nearBy' 
    get 'search'
  end

  resources :ratings
  get '/rate_user', to: 'ratings#rate_user', via: [:put, :patch], as: :rate_user

  get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  get 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
  root 'home#mainPage'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :ratings do
  collection do
    get 'rate_user'
  end
end
resources :ratings
```

in the view you should have something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Rate User', rate_user_ratings_path %>
```

Comment: By doing your way, i am getting ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/ratings/rate_user.42"):

Comment: What is the controller filename?

Comment: file name is ratings_controller.rb

Comment: Do you have "resources :ratings" alone in route.rb?

Comment: with your new answer, i got ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Rating with 'id'=rate_user):

Comment: Remember to put "resources : ratings" at the end

Comment: can you just tell me what happened in my case and what did you do ?

Comment: rating_path route is defined with "resources :ratings"

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change `f.submit` in your `form_for` to a `link_to rate_user_path`. Then in `routes`, I would do:

```
get '/rate_user', to: 'ratings#rate_user', via: [:put, :patch], as: :rate_user
```

This way you are setting a specific route for accessing the `rate_user` method.

#### Edit:

I recreated your problem with:

**Ratings_controller:**

```
...

  def index
    @rating = Rating.new
  end

  def rate_user
    @rating = Rating.new
    redirect_to ratings_path
  end
...
```

**Routes:**

```
...
resources :ratings 
get '/rate_user', to: 'ratings#rate_user', via: [:put, :patch], as: :rate_user
...
```

**View** and **Partial:**

```
...
<%= render 'edit_rating' %>
...

<%= form_for @rating do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :foo%>
  <%= f.text_field :bar  %>
  <%= link_to "Rate", rate_user_path  %>
<%end%>
```

And everything works. Double check your routes for typos. Make sure you switched the `f.submit` to a `link_to`.

Comment: getting ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ratings/rate_user")

Comment: @RahulDess can you add `rake routes` to your OP?

Comment: @RahulDess trying to recreate your app. Give me a few. Meanwhile, fix the typo in routes. Says `resource` instead of `resources` for `ratings`